# How to detect position of last pressed key in a string in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, string, position

I'm entering data in a datagridview.

Say I've entered `678.56` in a cell. Now if I again press digit 6 after 678,

I want to know the last pressed key's position in the string. Text.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) is giving me position 0 (as there is also a 6).

But I need to know the currently pressed key's position. I'm using `KeyPress` event.

Edit: I'm using string value taken from a cell of datagridview. It's not a textbox. I'm creating a eventhandler as KeyPress.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Did you debug? What is the KeyChar your getting in e.KeyChar property?

Comment: @zenwalker I'm getting the ascii code for 6 in e.KeyChar. But IndexOf(e.KeyChar) is giving me value of 0 as there is also a 6 in 0 position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the character before [TextBox.SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx).

Comment: thank you very much. Your suggestion helped me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this in your `KeyPress` event:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        int position = textBox1.SelectionStart;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the KeyRelease event, that's when the e.KeyChar will return the value of the key pressed (released in this case).

Comment: I've to use KeyPress event because of other validation for the program.